# linear regression vs linear mixed effect model coefficients

Tags: regression, mixed-model, linear

It is my understanding that linear regression models and linear mixed effect regression models will produce the same regression coefficients (i.e., fixed effects); however, linear regression models produce downwardly biased standard errors leading to inflated Type I error (Cohen, Cohen, Aiken, & West, 2003). Yet, I have a dataset where the linear regression and mixed model coefficients are orders of magnitude different and I do not understand why. The regressions have only one predictor and I estimate a random effect for just the intercept in the linear mixed effect regression model. Does anyone know the conditions under which the model coefficients will be discrepant?

As requested by a comment, here is my R code and output as well as the dataset attached. Notice the linear regression slope is twice the linear mixed effect model fixed slope and the intercepts have different signs!

```
lm1 <- lm(Y ~ X, data = d); lm1$coefficients
(Intercept)    X 
  -1.132507    1.184904 
lmer1 <- lmer(Y ~ X + (1 | ID), data = d); lmer1@beta
[1] 1.6767616 0.6376439

ID
1.00
1.00
1.00
2.00
2.00
2.00
3.00
3.00
3.00
4.00
4.00
4.00
5.00
5.00
5.00
6.00
6.00
6.00
7.00
7.00
7.00
8.00
8.00
8.00
9.00
9.00
9.00
10.00
10.00
10.00
11.00
11.00
11.00
12.00
12.00
12.00
13.00
13.00
13.00
14.00
14.00
14.00
15.00
15.00
15.00
16.00
16.00
16.00
17.00
17.00
17.00
18.00
18.00
18.00
19.00
19.00
19.00
20.00
20.00
20.00

Y
1.00
2.00
3.00
5.00
4.00
6.00
7.00
8.00
9.00
2.00
3.00
4.00
5.00
5.00
6.00
7.00
6.00
8.00
3.00
4.00
2.00
1.00
2.00
1.00
5.00
6.00
4.00
7.00
8.00
9.00
8.00
8.00
7.00
6.00
4.00
2.00
4.00
5.00
6.00
6.00
7.00
5.00
3.00
4.00
2.00
1.00
2.00
3.00
4.00
2.00
3.00
5.00
6.00
4.00
7.00
8.00
6.00
9.00
8.00
9.00

X
3.00
4.00
3.00
6.00
4.00
6.00
6.00
8.00
5.50
4.00
3.00
5.50
5.00
7.00
5.50
7.00
4.50
6.00
4.00
3.00
4.00
2.50
4.00
3.00
6.00
6.00
6.50
7.00
8.00
7.00
7.00
5.50
6.00
6.50
4.00
4.00
3.50
5.00
4.00
5.50
7.00
4.50
4.50
6.00
5.50
2.00
3.00
6.00
3.00
4.50
3.00
5.00
6.00
3.00
7.50
7.50
5.50
6.50
7.00
6.00
```

Comment: Can you share your code and data?  And I assume that the difference in the to types of models is the covariance structure?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that I can give a rigorous theoretical explanation, but a picture may make things clearer:

[image]

- The blue line is the OLS fit, the gray line is the population-level prediction for the mixed model. The individual lines are predicted lines (all equal slopes, randomly varying intercepts) for each ID.
- Since there is some correlation between the mean values of X and Y for each group, some of the variability that would go into the slope is instead taken out by the random intercept term.
- The apparently large difference in the intercepts is partly caused by extrapolation (the data starts at X=2, the intercept refers to the expected value at X=0).

---

```
d <- data.frame(ID=factor(rep(1:20,each=3)),
                Y=c(1,2,3,5,4,6,7,8,9,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,6,
                    8,3,4,2,1,2,
                    1,5,6,4,7,8,9,8,8,7,6,4,
                    2,4,5,6,6,7,5,3,4,2,1,2,
                    3,4,2,3,5,6,4,7,8,6,9,8,9),
                X=c(3,4,3,6,4,6,6,8,5.5,4,3,5.5,5,7,5.5,7,4.5,6,4,
                    3,4,2.5,4,3,6,6,6.5,7,8,7,7,5.5,6,6.5,4,4,3.5,
                    5,4,5.5,7,4.5,4.5,6,5.5,2,3,6,3,4.5,3,5,6,3,
                    7.5,7.5,5.5,6.5,7,6))

lm1 <- lm(Y ~ X, data = d)
library(lme4)
lmer1 <- lmer(Y ~ X + (1 | ID), data = d)
ff <- fixef(lmer1)
## get predictions
pp <- d
pp$Y <- predict(lmer1)
library(dplyr)
pp <- pp %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(Y %in% range(Y))

library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(d,aes(X,Y,colour=ID))+
    geom_point()+
    scale_colour_discrete(guide=FALSE)+
    geom_line(data=pp)+
    scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,8))+
    geom_smooth(method="lm",aes(group=1),fullrange=TRUE)+
    geom_abline(slope=ff["X"],intercept=ff["(Intercept)"],
                colour="darkgray",lwd=1.5)
ggsave("CV161703.png")
```

Comment: Thanks for creating that visualization Ben. I wonder if the difference has something to do with the assumed normal distribution of the group intercepts (i.e., random effect). If the variance of the random effect was estimated non-parametrically and could come from any distribution, perhaps the results would be more commensurate.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this image 100 times! I've been working to learn about mixed models, and some books I've looked at don't so much as mention the words "population averaged models", which are the three key words for a new-comer in easily understanding this topic (plus this picture).My next question is: How is prediction done--with the individual group's intercept?  Surely not the population mean line (grey)? And isn't the whole point that whatever group was observed is just one of many, and so the group we predict on will have a slope we know nothing about? (PS glmmTMB is amazing, thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

By context, I infer that "mixed" coefficients means linear combinations, not products. In other words, linear transforms from:

$$ Y = \alpha + \beta_{1}*X_{1} + \beta_{2}*X_{2} +\beta_{3}*X_{3} + ... +  \epsilon
$$
to
$$ Y = \alpha + \phi_{1}*\theta_{1} + \phi_{2}*\theta_{2} +\phi_{3}*\theta_{3} + ... +  \epsilon
$$
where, say, $$\theta_{1} = 0.707*X_{1} - 0.707*X_{2} \\
\theta_{2} = 0.707*X_{1} + 0.707*X_{2} \\
\theta_{3} = 0.707*X_{3} - 0.707*X_{1}
$$
You can run the regression on the $\theta$s and then reverse the linear transform to get the $\beta$s.  They **will be the same** as in the original regression, as will $\alpha$, and even the vector representing the $\epsilon$s.

The difference is that in the standard errors and p-values for the $\phi$s versus the $\beta$s.  If, for example, $\theta_{1}$ is the first principal component, it is quite possible that $\phi_{1}$ will have a lower p-value than any of the betas.

**Bottom line:** Same betas (once the transform is reversed), same R^2, same AIC. Conversely different p-values. ***There will be no adverse results in the estimates of the coefficients*** (other than round-off error, which is usually hardly noticeable).

**P.S.** If there a large differences in the range and/or variance of the X's, there are advantages to [standardizing (or normalizing) the predictors](http://www.benetzkorn.com/2011/11/data-normalization-and-standardization/) before running the regression.  This will, among other things, improve the interpretability of the regression results.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts, but this does not address the question. I am comparing OLS regression and LME regression (aka multi-level modeling).

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that both of your assumptions here are not necessarily valid:

1. models will produce the same regression coefficients
2. linear regression models produce downwardly biased standard errors

Regarding 1 - the models don't have to produce the same regression coefficients. The $\beta$ solution for LMM's are basically a GLS (generalized least squares) solution (though done numerically as we also have to estimate the variance components, either through ML or REML). And GLS solutions are not necessarily the same as OLS solutions. Your data clearly shows this.

I think (based on intuition, I didn't try to prove it rigorously) that the only way that the coefficients will be exactly the same is if you have a single binary variable, and the exact same size for each group (ID). In any other scenario I assume there will be at least some small variations, if not big ones.

Regarding 2 - linear models can sometime estimate higher variances for the coefficients, hence masking true effects. Here's an example in `R`:

```
set.seed(247)

n = 10
id = c(rep(1,n), rep(2,n), rep(3,n), rep(4,n))
drug = rep(c(rep(0,n/2), rep(1,n/2)),4)
eff = 1
random_intercept = rep(rnorm(4, sd=10),each=10)
noise = rnorm(4*n)
score = eff*drug + random_intercept + noise
data = data.frame(ID=id, Drug=drug, Score=score)

# Model A: regular linear regression - drug insignificant
fit.A = lm(Score~Drug, data=data)
coef(summary(fit.A))

# Model B: accounting for repeated measurements - drug significant
fit.B = lmer(Score ~ Drug + (1 | ID), data=data)
coef(summary(fit.B))
```